# Package install not recognized in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just ran a pip install for python package tweepy, but when I attempt to launch in Jupyter, I'm receiving a 'No Module named tweepy' error.

I'm assuming this is because tweepy is registered as pypi when I bring up the anaconda package list, but not sure the workaround to get this to work in my notebook.

[Anaconda package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzVnT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conda to install the package:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

Source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy

Comment: Is there a reason pip doesn't work in this case? And what is the difference between the above solution vs. just doing a basic conda install tweepy ?

Comment: Just tried the above solution and still getting the same error

Comment: It is not clear to me why it does not work with pip. You could try to install it from within anaconda using `!pip install tweepy`. And did you make sure that your notebook is running in the same environment? 
With the `-c` flag you denote the channel and conda inc. recommends installing tweepy from the conda-forge channel.

Comment: @JohnGlinski any success?